# How to solve getting repeatedly "hacked" on basic 18.04 VPS setup

Tags: 18.04, hacking

I have VPS with clean installation of Ubuntu 18.04 (provided by hosting) to host my private testing website. I set it up (Apache, MySQL...) three times, but I always get shut down by host provider because of complaints from other places.

They give me logs of attempted connections:

```
6 connection attempts from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 32928 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 7001
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 54944 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 8983
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 34258 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 9001
```

I don't know if problem is with the server OS itself it is web application (Laravel 7).

To set up server I basically do:

```
ufw app list
ufw allow OpenSSH
ufw enable
ufw status

sudo apt update
sudo apt install apache2

sudo ufw app list
sudo ufw app info "Apache Full"
sudo ufw allow in "Apache Full"

sudo apt install mysql-server
sudo mysql_secure_installation
mysql
SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'; //I change this...
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit

sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install php7.3 libapache2-mod-php7.3 php7.3-cli php7.3-mysql php7.3-gd php7.3-imagick php7.3-recode php7.3-tidy php7.3-xmlrpc php7.3-common php7.3-curl php7.3-mbstring php7.3-xml php7.3-bcmath php7.3-bz2 php7.3-intl php7.3-json php7.3-readline php7.3-zip

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git composer -y


sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
<Directory /var/www/> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks //delete "Indexes"
sudo systemctl restart apache2

sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo systemctl restart apache2
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
<Directory /var/www/> 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None // change None to All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Then I pretty much create database, upload website files to /html/ and get shut down few days later.

Am I'm doing something obviously wrong? How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Did your host provider inform you how these other system are connecting to you?  There is no further information?  Your installation of Ubuntu is up to date, I presume?

Comment: I'm making attempts to connect to them. Yes, up to date.

Comment: In the comments you say you are trying to connect to them. In the question you imply they are trying to connect to you. Which is it?